# convex function, inequality

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If $f: R^n\rightarrow R$ is convex and $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x), \alpha \geq 0$, show that:
a) $f(x+y)\leq f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in R^n$
b) $f(0)\geq 0$
c) $f(-x)\geq -f(x)$ for all $x\in R^n$
d) $f(\alpha_1 x_1 +...+\alpha_m x_m)\leq \alpha_1f(x_1)+...+\alpha_mf(x_m)$ for all $\alpha_k>0, x_k\in R^n, k=1, .., m$

Can you help me to prove these inequalities? I apologize for writing them all in one question, but I can't write more questions here today and I need solutions for tomorrow morning.

Comment: What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @Landscape I corrected b). Thanks.

Comment: @user23709: You are welcome. Please note that in fact $f(0)=0$(let $\alpha=0$).

Comment: @copper.hat I now have problem with a) and d), since I got answer for b) and c). I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: For a) (and d is similar), note that $x+y = 2 (\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2} y)$. Use convexity to obtain an upper bound on $f(\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2} y)$ and positive homogeneity to finish the proof.

Comment: I've done it. So easy :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your function is continuous. We have for $t \in (0,1)$
\begin{equation}
f(tx+(1-t)x) \le tf(x) + (1-t)f(y) \le tf(x) +f(y)
\end{equation}
Doing $t $ tends to one we obtain a).

To b) $f(0) = f(0x) =0f(x) =0$.

to c) $0 = f(x-x) \le f(x) +f(-x)$

To d) a do simple indction of a)

Comment: So, in c) you used part a) ?

Comment: You don't need to invoke continuity here, and the above does **not** show subadditivity. It just shows $f(x) \le f(x)+f(y)$ (assuming the second $x$ was meant to be $y$). (Any convex function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, but this is not required here.)